# Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 11, in <module>

Tags: python, discord.py

There is this "Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 11, in 
@client.command()
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'" error coming is there something i did wrong in the code?

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions, is_owner
import json

client = discord.Client(command_prefix = ".")
status=discord.Status.idle

@client.command()
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send("member is banned")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


my_secret = os.environ['Token']

client.run(my_secret)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try to do any [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before asking? For example, did you try reading the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), or using any of the resources described there (there is a FAQ page and a Discord server)?

Comment: The answer is that `discord.Client` does not provide `Command`; that comes from `Bot`.

Comment: Another way you can solve this problem is to [copy and paste from the error message into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27Client%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27command%27). This will immediately show you multiple duplicates of the question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `client = discord.Client(command_prefix = ".")`

to

`client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')`

Answer (score 0):

```
# You have to write 
# client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
# then you only write  client.command() in line (11)
# And you have to also import from discord.ext import commands in line 2

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot is Online")

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Pong")

client.run('WRITE YOUR TOKEN HERE')
```